# How do I Break a "while True" Loop With a Command?

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm building a simple timer program that is supposed to turn off when you tell it to (using the SpeechRecognition module), but so far it only turns off while it's listening to you and then keeps going (it repeats as a "listen, sound alarm, repeat" sort of way).

The function for the alarm looks like this:

```
def alarms():
while True:
    h1 = '08:00 AM'
    h2 = '01:00 PM'
    h3 = '08:30 PM'
    t = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
    text = record_audio()
    while t == h1 or t == h2 or t == h3:
        ps('alarm.mp3')
        time.sleep(1)
        if turn_off(text):
            print("hello")                      #This was just to test if it was listening to me
            break
```

In case you also need the function for the "turn off" section, here it is:

```
    offWords = ['stop', 'will stop', 'i\'m here', 'turn off']
    text = text.lower()

    for phrase in offWords:                    #determines if what you said includes anything in the list
        if phrase in text:
            return True
    return False
```

I haven't tried other methods since I'm still a beginner, but I feel like there's something more efficient than what I'm doing here. The program also has two other bugs:

1. When you run the program, it waits for you to say something before the alarm sounds (the alarm should be the first thing that pops up).
2. If you say anything other than the phrases in the "offWords" variable list, the alarm runs but it doesn't stop to listen anymore.

I don't know if they tie back to the main problem at all, but I'm including them just to be safe. I spent all day yesterday trying to solve this, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you problem here is that 'break' only escapes from one loop; and you have two nested loops. So, to escape from the outer loop, you need to add a condition on the outer loop. Like this, for example:

```
def alarms():
    on = True
    while on:
        h1 = '08:00 AM'
        h2 = '01:00 PM'
        h3 = '08:30 PM'
        t = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        text = record_audio()
        while t == h1 or t == h2 or t == h3:
            ps('alarm.mp3')
            time.sleep(1)
            if turn_off(text):
                on = False
                print("hello")
                break
```

Now, instead of being a "while true", you're checking whether the alarm is still on. Alteranatively, since this function has nothing else on it, you could just return:

```
def alarms():
    while True:
        h1 = '08:00 AM'
        h2 = '01:00 PM'
        h3 = '08:30 PM'
        t = time.strftime('%I:%M %p')
        text = record_audio()
        while t == h1 or t == h2 or t == h3:
            ps('alarm.mp3')
            time.sleep(1)
            if turn_off(text):
                print("hello")
                return
```

This is a bit of an annoying problem, since sometimes you want to escape from more complex nested loops, a modification like this is not always that practical; and you'll end up needing an additional "if not on: break" on the outer loop for that check.

To solve this problem some languages provide you with "labeled loops" or "break " so that you can specify what loop you want to escape or how many loops you want to escape; these however if abused make the code less clear, which is why [Python did not include this feature](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3136/).

By the way, your first problem is caused by you trying to record before sounding the alarm - you'll probably want to ring it at least once before starting recording. And for the second one, think about the inner loop: you'll stay inside it during all the time you're ringing, right? So you'll want to do the recording inside it, not outside.

Comment: Thanks, Leonardo!! Your first code did it--I never thought of assigning the boolean values to a variable. As for your other two suggestions, they make a lot of sense. I haven't gotten down to implementing them yet, but still, thanks.